# Compilation error on fedora 14

Tags: fedora, compiling, c++, g++

I installed fedora version 14 using virtual box but when I try to compile a program then displayed command not found. After that I tried to install g++ compiler using commands but, the way I followed

```
[firnas@localhost ~]g++ -op firnas.cpp
Command not found
[firnas@localhost ~]$ su
password
[root@localhost firnas]#yum install gcc gcc-c++
Loaded plugins:langpacks,presto,refresh-packagekit Adding en_US to language list Error:Cannot retrieve repository metadata(repomd.xml) for repositery :fedora Please verify its path and try again.
```

I have to compile a c++ program perfectly.

So, what I have to do now? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: what yields `g++ --version` and `gcc --version`?

Answer (score 3):

Fedora 14 has hit its end of life. You won't find any of the YUM repositories necessary to do any installations such as this. You'll likely be able to find old RPMs which were part of F14 and may be able to install these manually, however.

But I'd encourage you to just go with a more recent version of Fedora, say 19 or 20.